# Proper way to nest a directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/A0s3kafWD1WIaFcwimIT?p=preview

I am trying to nest a directive inside another directive but it is not working.

Angular:

```
app.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>Hello Parent</div>'
  }
})


app.directive('childtest', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>Hello Child</div>'
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<test>
  <childtest>  
  </childtest>
</test>
```

How do I correctly do this?

Comment: Have a look at `ng-transclude`. I'll see if I can post an example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it very much depends on your actual use-case, but you have some options:

- Don't give the parent directive a template:

  ```
  app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E'
    }
  });

  app.directive('childtest', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div>Hello Child</div>'
    }
  });
  ```

  HTML

  ```
  <test>
    <childtest>  
    </childtest>
  </test>
  ```
- Put the children in the template of the parent:

  ```
  app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div>Hello parent <childtest></childtest></div>'
    }
  });

  app.directive('childtest', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div>Hello Child</div>'
    }
  });
  ```

  HTML

  ```
  <test></test>
  ```
- Give the parent a template, and use transclusion to move the child directive to inside the template

  ```
  app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div>Hello Parent <div ng-transclude></div></div>'
    }
  });

  app.directive('childtest', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div>Hello Child</div>'
    }
  });
  ```

  HTML

  ```
  <test>
    <childtest>  
    </childtest>
  </test>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I *think* what you are looking for here is `ng-transclude`. What it does is it allows you to keep any child elements inside of your custom directive - all the while still allowing you to add elements either before or after those child elements.

Including this, basically your parent directive changes to:

```
app.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div>Hello Parent<div ng-transclude></div></div>'

  }
});
```

The `<div ng-translcude></div>` tells angular exactly where you want the child included at and adding the `transclude: true` tells angular that you want to have this behavior. Take a look at your updated plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/HL9PD6U4V7p56T3Cqx5F?p=preview